# Array com as ordens dos campos ao invés do ID

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma dificuldade aqui. Tenho duas tabelas, `cursos` e `alunos_inscritos`. A tabela de alunos possui um id(auto_increment), que grava o código do curso a cada inscrição. Gostaria de gerar uma lista de presença na ordem tipo, 1,2,3 e assim por diante, que invés de trazer o ID da tabela, traz a posição do array. Não sei se fui claro. Vejam meu código.

```
$dados = connection::select("select * from alunos where id_curso=5")

foreach ($dados as $reg) {

$ordem = array($reg['id'],$ordem)

$tabela .= '<table width:100%;"> 
            <tr>
            <td>' . $ordem . '</td>
            <td>' . $reg['nome'] . '</td>
            </tr>
            </table>';

  }
```

Comment: `foreach ($dados as $reg as $key) {` `$key` é o indice atual do array.

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: é que esse código seria foreach ($dados as $key => $reg) , dai o $key é a chave, Mas poderia usar tbm array_keys();

Comment: Consegui acertar pessoal. Obrigado.

Comment: Como inicio o $key na segunda posição, pra não mostrar o zero.